# Python: SSL Certificate Verify Fails for Most Websites

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, anaconda, ssl-certificate

Recently I had to uninstall an old version of Anaconda from 2018 (Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe, Python 3.6.3) on my Windows 10 laptop, as I've been unable to install newer versions of Python and of some packages on it. I tested 3 different Anaconda versions (2021.11, 2021.04 and 2020.07) with various versions of Python 3.8 and 3.9 installed by default, and encountered a few problems since then:

- When launching Jupyter Notebook, only the base environment is discoverable by default. No other conda environment is discovered unless I add it manually. This wasn't previously the case.
- When using urllib or requests to access data from websites, almost every website that worked with my old Anaconda/Python configuration now returns a SSL certificate verify failed error. It works for a handful of websites (e.g., Google), but fails for a vast majority of websites (e.g., Wikipedia, Stack Overflow).

The error message is as follows:

```
>>> import urllib.request as urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\http\client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\http\client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\http\client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\http\client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\http\client.py", line 1454, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Users\Tomer\Anaconda3\envs\main\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:997)>
```

I tried to replicate where things stopped working by (1) recreating my old Anaconda3 environment where I was able to access URLs via urllib, and (2) running 'conda install certifi', which forced numerous other packages to update as well as bringing back the SSL certificate verify error. A comparison of a few of the package differences is as follows:

```
#       Name                      Version                   Build  Channel

Works:  openssl                   1.0.2o               h8ea7d77_0  
Broken: openssl                   3.0.3                h8ffe710_0    conda-forge

Works:  ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
Broken: ca-certificates           2021.10.8            h5b45459_0    conda-forge

Works:  certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0  
Broken: certifi                   2021.10.8       py310h5588dad_2    conda-forge
```

I've never encountered any type of error like this before so I'm not sure if these are the primary responsible packages or if some other package that updated (e.g., pypi, python 3.10 or 3.9) might have caused this error to start occurring, or if it might be an error on my computer's end that goes beyond Anaconda.

Any tips or help in trying to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I've since removed Anaconda altogether and installed Miniforge3 (Miniforge3-4.12.0-0-Windows-x86_64.exe) with Python 3.9.10 - the exact same issue replicates there as well, so it's not exclusively limited to Anaconda. I am also able to access these websites directly on my browser, so I suspect it may not have to do with my computer but rather with Python.

Answer (score 0):

CAN you check using Firefox ? Firefox uses its own certificate. If it works, it means you need to update certificate authorities.